# My help book keeps loading, never displays

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa, help-viewer

My app points to a help book in its plist file :

```
<key>CFBundleHelpBookFolder</key>
<string>MyApp.help</string>
<key>CFBundleHelpBookName</key>
<string>com.bruno.myapp.help</string>
```

The help book's structure is as follows :

```
MyApp.Help > Contents > Info.plist, Resources > English.lproj > index.html, InfoPlist.strings
```

The help book's property list seems fine too :

[image]

When I add it to my XCode project, then launch the help section of my app, nothing shows. The Help Viewer just keeps loading for a long while (spinner at the top) until it stops and the help window's still blank.

Every time I restart my computer the changes I might have made to the help book also get lost.

There are no errors in the Console.

Comment: Why do you have capital H in "MyApp.Help" folder name? Anyway look inside the Mac App Store.app -> do it like they do it.

Comment: just mistyped, it doesn't change anything though, I modelled my help book after Mail.help. Maybe I'm overlooking something, not sure.

Comment: Try to copy their help bundle (link it) and see if it works. At least you can narrow down problem.